# Key-Value-Coding Key paths

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

can someone give me a tutorial about key paths in Cocoa KVC concept, because I can't understand them. I understand what they do, but how they do it? I'll really prefer a tutorial with sample example, all tuts I could find are with very low amount of information, and examples are missing most of the times.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly I was not able to find a tutorial along with a sample code that is easy to attain.
The following web page on [KVO and KVC](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/how-cocoa-bindings-work-via-kvc-and-kvo) is very short, simple, with code, and explains the most basic concepts of KVC and KVO very well.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations, it's your lucky day! It turns out, apple thought that this would be important too, so they created a shiny and fancy guide for you right on their site, which you can view [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1).

Comment: Man you are so thoughtful. How did i miss it?